# BrokerConnect Issue

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

I have a kafka producer written in python that I have added to docker-compose.yml

Producer:

```
import os, csv, avro.schema, json
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from collections import namedtuple

output_loc = '{}/avro.avro'.format(os.path.dirname(__file__))
CSV = '{}/oscar_age_male.csv'.format(os.path.dirname(__file__))
fields = ("Index","Year", "Age", "Name", "Movie")
csv_record = namedtuple('csv_record', fields)

p = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = ['localhost:9092', 'kafka:9092'], value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))

def read_csv(path):
    with open(path, 'rU') as data:
        data.readline()
        reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=",")
        for row in map(csv_record._make, reader):
            yield row

def parse_schema(path='{}/schema.avsc'.format(os.path.dirname(__file__))):
    with open(path, 'r') as data:
        return avro.schema.parse(data.read())

def serilialise_records_and_send(records, outpath=output_loc):
    schema = parse_schema()
    with open(outpath, 'w') as out:
        writer = DataFileWriter(out, DatumWriter(), schema)
        for record in records:
            record = dict((f, getattr(record, f)) for f in record._fields)
            writer.append(record)
            msg = p.send(topic='test', value=record)
            metadt = msg.get()
            print(metadt.topic)
            print(metadt.partition)

serilialise_records_and_send(read_csv(CSV))
```

when I run the docker-compose my producer image fails due to no brokers available.

can anyone enlighten me as to why the brokers aren't available?

when I run the producer locally from IDE I can connect so unsure what's missing

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.4.0"
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - '32181:32181'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"  
      
  kafka:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.4.0"
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '29092:29092'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"  
      
  schema-registry:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest"
    hostname: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:32181
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS: GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN: '*' 
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

      
  kafdrop:
    image: "obsidiandynamics/kafdrop"
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:29092
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms32M -Xmx64M"
      SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXTPATH: "/"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
  
  producer:
    image: "producer"
    ports: 
      - '5000:5000'
    environment: 
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:29092
    depends_on: 
      - kafka
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hardcoding the broker host and port

```py
p = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = ['localhost:9092', 'kafka:9092'], value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
```

but when running under Docker you need to connect to the listener that is correct for that network, namely `kafka:29092` (which you have included at `KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT` but I don't see it being read in your code).

So either update your code to use the environment variable, or change your hardcoded list to

```py
p = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = ['localhost:9092', 'kafka:29092'], value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
```

See [this blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/) for thorough background on Kafka listeners, Docker, etc.

Comment: made suggested changes but issue persists

Comment: Did you read the blog?

Comment: yes I cant seem to resolve this Ill keep researching Thanks.

Comment: Try `bootstrap_servers = ['kafka:29092']` on its own

Answer (score 0):

You've defined an environment variable for Kafka. You should use it

```
import os
p = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = [os.environ['KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT']])
```

You cannot use `localhost` while the code runs within the container because that refers to *that* service, not the broker

---

However, the more generalized solution to the code you've shown is to use the [CSV SpoolDir Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-spooldir/current/connectors/csv_source_connector.html#csv-source-connector-examples)